# Django cannot read Arabic from uploaded .xls file

Tags: python, django, parsing, xls

When uploading a .xls file containing Arabic to my Django website, I get the following error when running code:

UnicodeDecodeError
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 655224: character maps to

Here is my python / django code (it is original without any decoding as I tried many variants they all failed):

```
#certain_file is the uploaded file
certain_file = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['certain_file'].file,  encoding=request.encoding)

with certain_file as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, "html.parser")
#rest of code
```

My goal is to parse uploaded file.

Many thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I have never had any instance of me trying to parse a foreign language in python, but it is most likely because python can't read any encoding for those characters.

Comment: TIL Django has a M$ Word support...